# How to group databases in folders in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

My question comes from the frustration that I have every time I launch SSMS. We have few hundred of different databases in one server instance, from different projects and customers,  and having them in one long flat tree view just does not feel very ergonomic to me.

Is there any smart way to keep them more organized? I thought, that for example being able to group them in custom folders would be a nice solutions, but AFAIK SSMS does not support it.

Being able to group stored procedures in a similar way would be a nice added value, but I'd be more than happy with being able to group databases only.

Comment: +1 But I don't think this is possible.

Comment: A couple of suggestions.  Set up more instances, only run the ones you need.  Detach unused databases - they can always be reattached in the future should they be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this before. With over 100 active customers and a few hundred databases relying on separate instances, it has not been a solution to a problem, even created additional issues, especially that majority of databases need to be online most of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have good news for all of you. There is an SSMS add-in for this. It allows to organize into custom folders all databases, stored procedures and other database objects as well. Just as if this was a native SQL Server Management Studio functionality.

The tool name is SQL Handy Groupie and can be found at [www.skilledsoftware.com](http://www.skilledsoftware.com). Have fun.

Comment: +1 A relevant answer. But I see both answers you have given involve this product. Are you affiliated with the company?

Comment: I don't suppose anyone knows of a cheaper or free version?

Comment: I've bought SQL Handy Groupie and I am dissappointed because it's full of bugs.

Comment: There is an SSMS add-in for grouping databases available at http://www.sqltreeo.com/wp/. I have not tried it though.

Comment: The link in the answer seems [broken](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/skilledsoftware.com).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here through a google search.
In SSMS Press `ctrl + alt + G` to open the Registered Server pane. There you can add a folder and add connection strings as `New Server Registration...`

[image: SSMS Registered Servers]