# Create database folder (SQL Management Studio) in C#

Tags: c#, database, ssms

I am building a small app with Linq to SQL and I need to create databases on the fly. So I was wondering if I could create a custom folder like the "System Databases" one in SQL Management Studio. Is this even possible or is SQL MS doing this internally?

EDIT: I need to be able to do this in C#, without any third party tools or frameworks.

[image]

Comment: you want to create custom database on the fly??

Comment: yep, I do it with Linq to SQL CreateDatabase() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSMS add-in for this. It allows to organize into custom folders all databases, stored procedures and so on.

Check this tool [SQL Handy Groupie](http://www.skilledsoftware.com/)

You can use this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356527/how-to-group-databases-in-folders-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we can't buy a third-party addin for only this purpose. The addin surely used some C# classes or frameworks to do what it does. If I could get a hold on those, that would suffice.