# Can I create sub-folder in stored procedure folder in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to create sub-folder in the stored procedure in sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is a "procedure folder" in that DBMS?

Comment: I use sql management studio

Comment: That is not a DBMS, but as it only works with SQL Server it's safe to assume you are using that.

Comment: This link might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4356527/4130289

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to create custom folders in SQL Server Management Studio.
There are third party add-ins that offer this feature (like SQLTreeo or SQL Handy Groupie)